# Use a grid system in Polymer

Tags: polymer-1.0

I have used MDL (Material Design Lite) and i realy like it, but I want to use something similar in Polymer, for example: mdl-grid (or others clases), does polymer have a component or similar to make a grid system like in MDL? or what do you recomend to use in Polymer to have a similar efect of those MDL clases?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend checking out [customelements.io](https://customelements.io/). It's a community page for web-components offering many reusable elements for Polymer.

Specifically the `ag-grid` and `fin-hypergrid` elements.

[https://customelements.io/search/grid](https://customelements.io/)